# Is there a way to apply logical not to a form validation rule?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there this possibility to have:

```
$config = array(
    array(
        'field'   => 'data', 
        'label'   => 'data1', 
        'rules'   => 'trim|required|!numeric'
    )
);
```

And the logic for that must be: trim it, required, and it must not be only numbers.
Any way to accomplish that without extending the library or writing my own functions? I want this data to be alpha_dash+numeric, not only numeric but can be only alpha.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can only use a callback

Comment: Yes you got to use a callback in the validation. Where you perform all the logical rules you want to and return TRUE or FALSE

Comment: Thank you, looks like it's better to make my own validation library